# ( test -n $st ) != ( test -z $st ) right?

Tags: shell-script, test

As I read,

`test -n $string` ==> Exit status is 0 if `$string` is **not null**, 1 otherwise

and

`test -z $string` ==> Exit status is 0 if `$string` **is null**, 1 otherwise

But in this particular example, (I tried to create a null string) it seems I am missing some thing.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
str=""
test -n $str
echo $?
test -z $str
echo $?
```

Output of this is:

```
0
0
```

[image]

Can anyone give an explanation for this strange behavior??

Comment: Please don't use images unless absolutely necessary.  Instead, copy and paste the text into your question and format with the `{}` button.  Images are not searchable and may also disappear over time as hosting services change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `$str` inside double quotes!

> The -n test requires that the string be quoted within the test brackets. Using an unquoted string with ! -z, or even just the unquoted string alone within test brackets (see Example 7-6) normally works, however, this is an unsafe practice. Always quote a tested string. [Other Comparison Operators](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)